# how to remove Trace 0 and Trace 1 in plotly line in Rshiny?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, trace, r-plotly

In Rshiny, the line plot displays a Trace 0 and Trace 1 on the right-hand top corner of the plot. Clicking on line 0 makes the line disappear while clicking on Trace 1 makes the text on top of the line to disappear. Code as below.

```
ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("fig1"))
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  Primates <- c('Potar monkey', 'Gorilla', 'Dinosaur', 'Rhesus monkey', 'Chimp')
  Bodywt <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
  Brainwt <- c(115, 406, 1320, 179, 440)
  data <- data.frame(Primates, Bodywt, Brainwt)
  
  fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Bodywt, y = ~Brainwt, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
  fig <- fig %>% add_text(text = data$Primates, textposition = 'top', textfont = list(color = '#000000', size = 16))
  fig <- fig %>% layout(title = 'Primates Brain and Body Weight',
                        xaxis = list(title = 'Body Weight (kg)',
                                     zeroline = TRUE),
                        yaxis = list(title = 'Brain Weight (g)',
                                     range = c(0,1400)))
  
  output$fig1 <- renderPlotly(fig)
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I need some help to remove Trace 0 and Trace 1.

Comment: Do you want to remove the legend or link the legend items (both traces are hidden in parallel)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a combined trace by using mode `'lines+text'`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("fig1"))
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  Primates <- c('Potar monkey', 'Gorilla', 'Dinosaur', 'Rhesus monkey', 'Chimp')
  Bodywt <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
  Brainwt <- c(115, 406, 1320, 179, 440)
  data <- data.frame(Primates, Bodywt, Brainwt)
  
  fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Bodywt, y = ~Brainwt, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+text', text = ~Primates, textposition = 'top', textfont = list(color = '#000000', size = 16))
  fig <- fig %>% layout(showlegend = TRUE,
                        title = 'Primates Brain and Body Weight',
                        xaxis = list(title = 'Body Weight (kg)',
                                     zeroline = TRUE),
                        yaxis = list(title = 'Brain Weight (g)',
                                     range = c(0,1400)))
  
  output$fig1 <- renderPlotly(fig)
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another work around. We can also add **showlegend = F** in layout to avoid Trace0 and Trace1 showing up.

Comment: Let me guess, you "found" it in my answer. Why didn't you clarify after I was asking in the comments?